# Not able to create index using Java high level Rest client

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I am using java high level rest client for integrating elasticsearch in my application,But not able to create an index

somewhere I found that to execute the request we need to use index(request) method (which I have commented in my code) but it is shwing that index(request) method is deprecated from the type RestHighLevelClient.

Here is my code:

```
@GetMapping("/createIndex")
public boolean createIndex() throws IOException {


    IndexRequest request = new IndexRequest(
            "muviuser", 
            "user",  
            "1");   
    String jsonString = "{" +
            "\"user\":\"Bran\"," +
            "\"postDate\":\"2018-01-30\"," +
            "\"message\":\"trying out Elasticsearch\"" +
            "}";
    request.source(jsonString, XContentType.JSON);

    //client.index(request);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-create-index.html) explains, here's how to create an index using the high-level ES API:

```
    CreateIndexRequest request = new CreateIndexRequest(indexName);
    request.mapping("_doc", mappingJson, XContentType.JSON);
    CreateIndexResponse response = client.indices().create(request);
```

Note that your `source` document looks wrong, as it needs to follow the specific [ES request format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-create-index.html#_providing_the_whole_source) with mappings, settings and aliases. Better to specify just the `mapping` instead.

Comment: That no longer seems to be accurate, a CreateIndexRequest no longer accepts a document type argument.

Comment: My post applies to ES 6.0. However, it still worked when I tried with ES 7.1.0.